# R studio, Excel, XLS files

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, r, power-query, rstudio

I have 20 excel (.XLS) files. Each excel contains 13 Sheets. All of these excel are in proper format. I wanted to extract sheet no.10 from each excel and paste the data into an Excel sheet. I want data from each sheet in one excel. I have been trying use R or R studio to do such this task. If any can help me to do it from R studio or through Excel Power Query or VBA will be helpful to me.

The attached is the table for one sheet I wanted to extract data from. As we can see we have mmales row starting from 27 Row and similary Females data after 44 the row. The data structure is same for Males, Female and Total.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This requires VBA.

The following VBA macro is based on the article
[Excel Macro: Extract Data from Multiple Excel Files (4 Methods)](https://www.exceldemy.com/excel-macro-extract-data-from-multiple-excel-files/),
where you will find more explanations of the code.

Warning : I have not tested this code, which task is left for you.

```
Sub ExtractDataToDifferentSheets()
    On Error GoTo HandleError
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim objectFlieSys As Object
    Dim objectGetFolder As Object
    Dim file As Object
    Set objectFlieSys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objectGetFolder = objectFlieSys.GetFolder("D:\saledata")       ' The folder location of the source files.
    Dim counter As Integer
    counter = 1
    For Each file In objectGetFolder.Files
        Dim sourceFiles As Workbook
        Set sourceFiles = Workbooks.Open(file.Path, True, True)
        Dim rowsNumber As Integer
        rowsNumber = sourceFiles.Worksheets(10).UsedRange.rows.Count
        Dim colsNumber As Integer
        colsNumber = sourceFiles.Worksheets(10).UsedRange.Columns.Count
        Dim rows, cols As Integer
        For rows = 1 To rowsNumber
            For cols = 1 To colsNumber
                Application.Workbooks(counter).ActiveSheet.Cells(rows, cols) = _
                       sourceFiles.Worksheets(10).Cells(rows, cols)
            Next cols
        Next rows
        rows = 0
        Dim worksheetName As String
        worksheetName = Replace(sourceFiles.Name, ".xlsx", "")
        sourceFiles.Close False
        Set sourceFiles = Nothing
        With ActiveWorkbook
            .ActiveSheet.Name = worksheetName
            counter = counter + 1
            If counter > .Worksheets.Count Then
                .Sheets.Add After:=.Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count)
            End If
            .Worksheets(counter).Activate
        End With
    Next
HandleError:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```